# Help with vector notation: something like a 'rotating shift'

Tags: notation, vectors

## Preface

I know that the title is not clear, if you want to change feel free to suggest an edit. I used the term *rotating shift* because is similar to the operation that one could perform on array in computer science.

## Question

Lets suppose I have these two vectors:

$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to write this operation

$$
k_1 \cdot (a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3) + k_2 \cdot (a_2 b_1 + a_3 b_2 + a_1 b_3) + k_3 \cdot (a_3 b_1 + a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_3)
$$

in a compact form. I could express the first term as:

$$
k_1 A^T B
$$

How could I express the others? There is a standard notation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following? 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1 & k_3 & k_2\\
k_2 & k_1 & k_3\\
k_3 & k_2 & k_1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1 \\
b_2 \\
b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that the "k" matrix is a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), with many interesting properties.

Another typical notation is the use of the cyclic sum operator: $\sum_{cyc}$. Your expression then becomes 
$$
k_1 \sum_{cyc} a_i b_{i} + k_2 \sum_{cyc} a_i b_{i+2}+ k_3 \sum_{cyc} a_i b_{i+1}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
k_1 \sum_{cyc} a_i b_{i} + k_2 \sum_{cyc} a_i b_{i-1}+ k_3 \sum_{cyc} a_i b_{i-2}
$$
Here, it is understood that there are three terms to be summed, and the indices are shifted cyclically, i.e. they go through the three positions, modulo 3.

Comment: Two good solution imho. However the first one is not applicable in my case (the $k$ terms are too long). But the second one is perfect in my case.

Comment: Yes, these are nice if the coordinates are going to be accessed directly. If cyclic permutations are only going to be used for the case of three, then using $P=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ you could use the circulant matrix identity to write this in a basically component free way as $\mathbf a\cdot (k_1 I+k_2P+k_3P^2)\mathbf b$, too.